# Arithmetic operation in NASM showing arbitrary character

Tags: assembly, nasm

Below is my code on NASM. I am taking two integers as user input (2 and 3) and want to add them then print to stdout. Input is taking correctly but as output it is showing some arbitrary character. What I am doing wrong? I believe something is wrong in adding input block but not sure what it is.

```
section .bss
fnum rest 255
lnum rest 255

section .text
global _start
_start:
        ; first input
        mov ecx, fnum
        mov edx, 255
        mov ebx, 0
        mov eax, 3
        int 80h

        ; second input
        mov ecx, lnum
        mov edx, 255
        mov ebx, 0
        mov eax, 3
        int 80h

        ; adding inputs 2 and 3
        mov eax, fnum
        add eax, ecx
        add eax, 48
        push eax
        mov eax, esp

        ;print output
        mov ecx, eax
        mov edx, 2
        mov ebx, 1
        mov eax, 4
        int 80h
```

Comment: The _same_ arbitrary character every time, or different every time?

Comment: same. something like this  ▒,   For simplicity I am taking inputs that will produce output less than 9.

Comment: you'll need to reinvent `printf("%d\n", ...)` to turn the contents of a register into a human-readable number, either by compiling in libc and calling `printf` or by doing it manually via something like https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/asm/Darwin/x86_64/hexip4todottedquad.s#L105

Comment: You're printing the low 2 bytes of the sum of the *addresses*, not the sum of the ASCII characters at the pointed-to locations.

Comment: @thrig I think the adding 48 accomplishes that, but I don't see the equivalent subtracting 48 from the inputs (or, more simply, subtracting 48 once and never adding it).

Comment: @thrig and peter, I did the same arithmatic operation successfully with static value assignment on register. I assigned numbers, added them, then converted to ascii and print with opcode. No issues with that. The problem is occuring when I am trying with user input.

Comment: @DanielH, will it be much to ask you to elaborate!

Comment: I won't be able to for a few hours and hopefully somebody else well answer by then. For the moment, though, what's the purpose of the `add eax, 48` line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read in the inputs, you ask for at least 255 bytes of text to be put into the locations `fnum` and `lnum`. You never read that text, and instead add the two memory addresses together (just the addresses, not the contents), and then add 48. You then print out the first two bytes of the result of that addition, which isn't actually what you want and isn't even meaningful.

You need to read the bytes read from those memory addresses (`[fnum]` instead of `fnum`), turn them into integers you can do arithmetic on, add *those* together instead of the memory addresses, turn the resulting number *back* into text, and then print the text.

For the simplest case, where both inputs and the output are single-digit nonnegative numbers (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9), you can convert from the character to the number by subtracting `0x30` (decimal 48), and you can convert from the number to the character by adding `0x30`. This is because the [ASCII digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) are consecutive, starting at character `0x30` being the digit 0. I believe your third line after the comment "adding inputs 2 and 3" is supposed to be this sort of conversion, but the thing you're converting isn't the output you want.

In NASM, you can write `0x30` as `'0'`, which makes the purpose more obvious to human readers.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. It worked like a charm. I've assigned like mov eax, [fnum] then sub eax, 48. did same for lnum and finaly during print added 48.

Comment: As a simplification, you can just subtract 48 once and not add it back, since `[fnum]` + `[lnum]` - 48 is mathematically equal to `[fnum]` - 48 + `[lnum]` - 48 + 48. I wouldn't recommend it because that would make the code harder to read, though.